# How Can I Assist IE's Flawed Garbage Collector?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, garbage-collection

I have a JavaScript application that uses XMLHttpRequest to fetch and parse about 60,000 XML documents. However, IE's memory usage grows quickly, and eventually the program crashes. I suspect this has to do with IE's JScript GC. Below is a simplified version of my code:

Above the code, I declare two variables:

```
var xmlhttp;
var xmlDoc;
```

When the code first starts running, I set the value of xmlhttp:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

The script then enters the main loop:

```
function loadXML() {

    xmlhttp.abort(); 
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml', 'Pragma', 'no-cache');
    xmlhttp.send("");
    while (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) { }
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    setTimeout("readXML()",0);

}


function readXML() {

    //Reads the XML.
    //If all data has been retrieved, exit loop.
    //Else, change the url and go back to loadXML()

}
```

Google Chrome runs the code just fine, with no errors. However, IE loops about 2000 times before crashing with an "Out of Memory" error. Is the Garbage Collector not doing it;s job? Can I rewrite my code to prevent problems?

Comment: that setTimeout(...,0) might be the problem, the 0 part I mean

Comment: No, the problem (unrelated to the leak though) is that he passes a string... and of course the fact that he's making the XHR synchronous just to handle the response asynchronously...

Comment: @Liviu Because the script loops between two functions so many times, the browser will freeze until the code terminates itself. As silly as it sounds, a 0 ms timeout will allow the browser to take control from the script, prevent the freeze.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'd appreciate some tips on how to correct my code. I'm not pro at JS, so I don't know everything! :)

Comment: @Michael: Regarding sync/async, see @phihag's answer. For the setTimeout, you would simply pass the function: `setTimeout(readXML, 0)` - but with the proper usage of the onreadystatechange event you won't need that anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a busy loop at all to wait for the result of an XMLHttpRequest. Also, there's no reason to have the `xmlhttp` object public. Instead, create a new one on every call and register a callback:

```
function loadXML() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml', 'Pragma', 'no-cache');
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        readXML();
      }
   };
   xmlhttp.send("");
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. It should take about 20 minutes to run.

Comment: In general, I think anyone would agree that a crash is better than a security hole.  Therefore, I encourage web-developers to exacerbate IE's GC problems whenever they can, so users will be inclined to replace their crashing IEs with real browsers, and thereby shut all those gaping security holes.  In the OP's case, the original code is so flawed, I'm going to give this answer a +1.

Comment: @Michael Oops, I forgot one thing. You shouldn't reuse xmlhttp objects. Updated the answer with the whole code. It shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds to run.

Comment: @phihag Thanks to your tips, it's looped about 4500 times and is only using about 5000KB! I've added you to the credits section.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely follow phihag's advice on a better way to process the xml requests and wait for their completion.

Then I would suggest nulling out your old xmlhttp object and creating a new one for each successive request so each old request can be entirely freed:

You don't show us how you go about running the same thing 60,000 times so I can't really help with the details of that code, but if the xmlhttp object itself is leaking some memory on each xmlhttp request, then throwing away the old object and creating a new one each time may help.

We also can't see what you're doing in readXML that could be leaking or what you're doing in the code that loops and gets the next request.  You could be leaking function closures, you could have circular object references, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've implemented both phihag's code and your `xmlhttp = null;` suggestion, and the script is working great! I've added you to the credits.